# "Breakpoint set/unset in gutter" event in extension while not debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Today, all breakpoints are sent only when the debugger is launched.

However, I want to be able to apply breakpoints as soon as the user clicks on the breakpoint gutter - but they might not actually be in "debug mode" or "debugging" in VS Code.

Is it possible to listen for this event from the extension side of things?

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints need validation, which requires a running debug adapter. That makes me think there's no other notification when breakpoints are modified.